# Defragmentation with TSHARK

Tags: tshark, defragmentation

I want to capture messages of Diameter protocol (over SCTP) by tshark on the screen, expanded.

First, I couldn't find what to write after switch '-f' to filter only diameter messages, but then I found the switch '-R' which accepted 'diameter'. 
So, currently my command seems like:

> `tshark -i el0 -R diameter -V`

This is all fine, at least, *until the packets are small enough*..

However, for bigger packets, I get the error `[Unreassembled Packet: DIAMETER]
    [Expert Info (Warn/Reassemble): Unreassembled Packet (Exception occurred)]
        [Message: Unreassembled Packet (Exception occurred)]`, 
and the packets are indeed not reassembled in the output.

I was googling for solution, and found that the below modification might do the defragmentation:

> `tshark -i el0 -R diameter -V -o ip.defragment:TRUE`

But it just doesn't help.

Any simple solution for this problem? (It is also ok to process the defragmentation *afterwards* somehow..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found it!

In wireshark there is a checkbox for several protocol related options, in particular, for diameter defragmentation you need to mark the checkbox

> `Reassemble fragmented SCTP user messages`

to get the long diameter messages properly displayed.

*Each of these protocol options has its own `tshark` correspondent* parameter, here you have to use 
  `-o sctp.reassembly:TRUE`.

(For general, look for the file `preferences` belonging to wireshark.)

So, what method finally worked is

1. First capture all (sctp) messages regularly:

> `tshark -i EL0 -f sctp  -w raw_capture.pcap`
>
> Then, if it is done, process the file by a further `tshark` command: 
>   `tshark -r raw_capture.pcap -R diameter -o sctp.reassembly:TRUE -V`